# Typescript with async and await: Variable is used before being assigned.ts(2454)

Tags: typescript, react-testing-library

Why is typescript complaining here that variable is unassigned? Am I missing something obvious with scopes?

```
test('test', async () => {
  let renderResult: RenderResult;
  await act(async () => {
    renderResult = render(<Component />);
  });

  await act(async () => {
    renderResult.rerender(<Component />);
  });
  // ERRROR: Variable 'renderResult' is used before being assigned.ts(2454)
  expect(renderResult.container.firstElementChild!.getAttribute('src')).toBe('original');
});
```

Comment: Afaik typescript does not analyze your act function. Without knowing the implementation details of `act()` there's no guarantee that your callback finishes before `expect()` is reached.

Comment: ok, fair enough. But then how should I restructure the code? Currently i've used @ts-ignore which seems to help, but...

Comment: I have the same question :). For now, you could say renderResult! wherever the compiler is complaining.

Answer (score 6):

You are getting this error, because you have [`"strictNullChecks": true`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks) in your tsconfig.json. So the compiler shows you that the variable is possibly has value of undefined.

Options here are

- to initialize the variable with a [null-object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) instance (or empty values like `""` for String, `[]` for Array, etc),
- to use
  [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) (
  `expect(renderResult!.container.firstEleme...`  ),
- disable the
  `strictNullChecks` in your tsconfig.json,
- or any other way of
  checking for undefined or asserting the value to be not undefined.

But IMHO if you are using `strictNullChecks`, you should consider using null-object pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler complains because it is undefined and you do not check for it before using it. moreover, as been said, the compiler cannot know what happens inside the async functions, so it cannot know if it is assigned eventually.

you can just use `expect(renderResult?.container?.firstElementChild!.getAttribute('src')).toBe('original');`

so you will get 'false' if anything in that chain is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to mark `renderResult` as `RenderResult` *or* `undefined`, and then accessing it with optional chaining at the end.

```
test('test', async () => {
  let renderResult: RenderResult | undefined
  await act(async () => {
    renderResult = render(<Component />);
  });

  await act(async () => {
    renderResult.rerender(<Component />);
  });
  // ERRROR: Variable 'renderResult' is used before being assigned.ts(2454)
  expect(renderResult?.container.firstElementChild!.getAttribute('src')).toBe('original');
});
```